# How can I represent strings in R without using "" or ''

Tags: r, string, integration, double-quotes

I have integrated R with another software that enforces the use of '', so I cannot use them in my R code.
I need to create a string with strings inside (because of html code) like this:
`<h1 style="color: #5e9ca0;">`
But this code must be inside a bigger string.

I've tried using paste0 but I still need to use 2 different types of representations for strings. Is there any other symbol to define a string in R besides "" and '' ? Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: Is this because you're worried about escaping chars?

Comment: I need to build a function like this:
Softwarefunction(' Rfunctionthatsendsemails(" htmlcodethatuses"" ") '

Comment: from [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-input-a-string-without-quote-td872607.html) thred: f = function(a) { 
    s = substitute(a) 
    as.character(s) 
}

Comment: That still does not solve my problem. I cannot create **string** variables with strings inside because of the '' limitation.
It would have to be something like:
`variable <- sendemail('<a href="https://refferencesite.com"><img src="https://imagesite.com"/>')`

Comment: You can escape quotes with `\ `: `a = 'quote \'within\' quotes'`

Comment: `variable <- sendemail('<a href=\"https://refferencesite.com\"><img src=\"https://imagesite.com\"/>')`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the policy on answers found elsewhere (not SO), but [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-input-a-string-without-quote-td872607.html) seem to do the trick.

```
f = function(a) { 
      s = substitute(a) 
       as.character(s) 
}

paste(f(a=this), f(a=is), f(a=my), f(a=string))
> [1] "this is my string"
```

or if you don't want quotes at all around your string, than use:

```
noquote(paste(f(a=this), f(a=is), f(a=my), f(a=string)))
>[1] this is my string
```

Comment: This may actually work because it defines strings without the use of "" at all. I'll try to use your function with the sendemail() function using "" in the html code inside.

Thank you for the idea, I'll edit this comment after testing it